# Download Instagram Image using PHP Curl or file_get_content

Tags: php, curl, instagram

I have this image that I'm trying to download
`https://www.instagram.com/p/CHZGLObDQV2/media/?size=l`
The issue with all Instagram images is that when you clicked on that URL it redirects you to the original URL which is:

```
https://instagram.fcrk2-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t51.2885-15/e35/s1080x1080/124374363_458291788482210_6691254472190084475_n.jpg?_nc_ht=instagram.fcrk2-1.fna.fbcdn.net&_nc_cat=106&_nc_ohc=VuSNajTRd78AX_GZlsF&_nc_tp=15&oh=cc224ca1041c97c06ec124a98e0241ca&oe=5FD536C4
```

How do I download that original URL of Instagram using `curl` or `file_get_contents`?

I have this code:

```
$url = "https://www.instagram.com/p/CHZGLObDQV2/media/?size=l";

save_image($url,"/test/images/test.jpg");

function save_image($img,$fullpath){
 $ch = curl_init ($img);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,1);
 $rawdata=curl_exec($ch);
 curl_close ($ch);
 if(file_exists($fullpath)){
  unlink($fullpath);
 }
 $fp = fopen($fullpath,'x');
 fwrite($fp, $rawdata);
 fclose($fp);
}
```

This one does not save properly because it does not get the original URL.

Your help is greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: @StackSlave - i get that when i access it using postman, but when via web browser, i am redirected to the original image URL. Have you tried accessing it into a web browser?

Comment: I tried the large URL, like: `header('Content-Description: File Transfer'); header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
  header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($url).'"'); header('Expires: 0');
  header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate'); header('Pragma: public');
  header('Content-Length: '.filesize($url)); readfile($url); die;` and just got nothing. They must be preventing you from seeing it unless you're on their Server.

Comment: hey anyone have any answer about this